# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: Can't clone sheet - unknown relation type found: http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/hdphoto

Tags: java, apache-poi, microsoft-office

En un proyecto que tenia tiempo de desarrollado últimamente se ha venido presentando un problema al momento de copiar hojas de excel. Por lo que he visto esta relacionado con imagenes dentro de la hoja. He buscado este problema, por un lado la solución a problemas similares es actualizar el POI, por otro lado no encuentro exactamente el problema con el relation type especifico, por lo que no se exactamente a que version de POI debería actualizar.

Actualmente uso poi 3.17. Actualice a 4.1.2 (Es el ultimo que aparece en mvnrepository) y el error continua.
El proyecto esta en java 8.

Gracias de antemano.

> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: Can't clone sheet - unknown relation type found: http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/hdphoto
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.addRelation(XSSFWorkbook.java:680)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.cloneSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:662)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.cloneSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:572)

Comment: La última versión que estoy viendo en Maven es la [5.2.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/5.2.2). ¿Cómo que la 4.1.2? Si te es posible y la versión de java que usas es compatible, actualiza hasta la última versión, y a partir de ahí empiezas a depurar el problema. Si usas java 8 como dices, puedes actualizar hasta la última sin problemas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez perdona. Lo que en realidad quería decir es que poi.ooxml-schemas esta hasta la versión 4.1.2.